# What's the exact inverse of if statement

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help with the exact reverse of the following line. I tried inserting Not ! but i think I must be putting it in wrong place.

```
if (email.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.lastIndexOf(".") < email.indexOf("@") + 2 || email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 >= email.length) {
    alert ("I need this to show when the exact opposite of the if statement occurs")
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Use email regex for email validation

Comment: A very simply reversal is to enclose the entire thing in `()` and put a `!` in front of that; `if (!(email... || .. ))`.

Comment: if (!(email.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.lastIndexOf(".") < email.indexOf("@") + 2 || email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 >= email.length))

Comment: @Tushar no, don't, please!   There's no sane regex for correctly validating email addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let's use [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if(email.indexOf("@") >= 1 && email.lastIndexOf(".") >= email.indexOf("@") + 2 &&
email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 < email.length)
{ 
    alert ("I need this to show when the exact opposite of the if statement occurs") 
};
```

just put negation on all literals and change "or" to "and"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (!(conditions))
```

```
if (!(email.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.lastIndexOf(".") < email.indexOf("@") + 2 || email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 >= email.length)) {
    alert ("I need this to show when the exact opposite of the if statement occurs")
}
```

Comment: Hey, your first answer ever! Indent code with four spaces to make it look like monospaced text. Someone did it for you.

Comment: It's better to use demorgans. Especially with a complex if like this. It just makes it easier to read and use in the long run

Comment: Yeah, I was learning about how indent a code when someone did it for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I agree Liam, but he said he didn't knew where put the !, so I preferred to gave him this example.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is..

```
if (!(email.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.lastIndexOf(".") < email.indexOf("@") + 2 || email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 >= email.length)) {
  alert ("I need this to show when the exact opposite of the if statement occurs")
}
```

You could also use [DeMorgans Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to negate the entire statement instead of wrapping in `!( )`.

```
if (email.indexOf("@" >= 1 && email.lastIndexOf(".") >= email.indexOf("@") + 2 && email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 < email.length) {
  alert ("I need this to show when the exact opposite of the if statement occurs")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can negate the result of any conditional by wrapping it in parentheses `(...)` and prefixing it with a `!`.

So, to naively negate the condition, say:

```
if (!(email.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.lastIndexOf(".") < email.indexOf("@") + 2 || email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 >= email.length)) {
...
```

However, this generally leads to unreadable code. To refactor the condition, use [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws:).

```
!(email.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.lastIndexOf(".") < email.indexOf("@") + 2 || email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 >= email.length)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(email.indexOf("@") >= 1 && email.lastIndexOf(".") >= email.indexOf("@") + 2 && email.lastIndexOf(".") + 2 < email.length)
```

To make this transformation, we changed each `||` to `&&` and negated each boolean operator in the expression.